# Github: page not found for post but opens for index.html

Tags: html, web, github

I'm creating a personal website for myself so I have my directory uploaded to github. The website is linked to githubusername.github.io and it works fine for me when I open it up but when I click on a post on that website, I get a "404 File not found" error from github.

The post has a link tag to minesweeper.html located in index.html.

`<a href="minesweeper.html"><img src="assets/img/Minesweeperimg.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">`

Here's a picture of my file structure.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I8NL.png)

Why am I getting the error and how do I fix it? When I run the html locally, it runs fine.

Comment: try adding a `/` before assets ?

Comment: Hey @run_time_error thanks for the answer! I'm new to this site so forgive my lack of knowledge of slackoverflow etiquette. I looked at the github repo and noticed that when I renamed Minesweeper.html to minesweeper.html, it didn't update the file on the github. I changed it and it works now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to call a file from your published Github Pages repo, the URL should be in this format:

```
https://<user>.github.io/<repository>/assets/README.md
```

So if your username is "gene", your file should be available on the URL:

```
https://gene.github.io/gene.github.io/minesweeper.html
```